# Set field exact size on indexed field

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have table in SQL-Server with 10 columns, one of is `IP` varchar(39). I store IP addresses here and this field has `secondary non-clustered index` because I perform `search` by this field.

The field set to 39 symbols and it is more than enough for IPv4. Will I gain performance benefit if I will set this field to exact IPv4 address size 15 symbols?

Comment: Setting it to `int` would conserve the most space, and avoid having to construct a horrific `CHECK` constraint to ensure that all digits are in the correct range. Why not do that? (Assuming that it's safe to go IPv4 only these days)

Comment: how can he set it to int,as IP address contains "." like 1.1.1.1?

Comment: @AnandPhadke - An IPv4 address is usually thought of as a 32 bit integer, conventionally *represented* as 4 groups of digits, each group being a number in the range 0-255, and separated by dots. But that's just a string formatting thing - all you really need is the 32 bit integer, and that *can* be stored in an `int` column.

Comment: I will stay with varchar39 because due to IPv6 which contain alphanumeric symbols.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The performance benefit is there but very small to take into account. But, if you data is of fixed length you should go with CHAR/NCHAR for it, as wasting storage space for some fixed data is not recommended.

Also, if by mistake you try to enter a bigger value for IPV4 address, you will not be able to do the same.

Answer (score 0):

There wont be any performance gain but you can save space.Thats it